# compare multiple colums with multiple matches

Tags: sql, compare

This is probably a really basic question for someone who knows what they are doing.  I have an oracle database.  Table is called shopping_list
fields are name, week and items.  Data is:

```
Name    Week    Item
Wendy   1       Soup
Wendy   1       Bread
Wendy   1       Eggs
Wendy   2       Soup
Wendy   2       Bread
Wendy   2       Eggs
Wendy   3       Chocolate
```

I want to find the entry where Wendy changed her order for the week - i.e. the entry for week 3.
I started with a simple comparison, where I did

```
select * from shopping_list
 join (select name, week, item) other
   on shopping_list.name =  other.name
  and shopping_list.week <> other.week
  and shopping_list.item <> other.item
```

but of course that gave me too many matches.
Then I tried

```
select shopping_list.name, shopping_list.week, shopping_list.item,
               other.name,         other.week,         other.item
  from shopping_list
  full outer join (select name, week, item from shopping_list) other
               on shopping_list.name = other.name
              and (shopping_list.week - 1) = other.week
              and shopping_list.item = other.item
```

and my results are:

```
wendy, 1, soup, null, null, null
wendy, 1, bread, null, null, null
wendy, 1, eggs, null, null, null
wendy, 2, soup, wendy, 1, soup
wendy, 2, bread, wendy, 1, bread
wendy, 2, eggs, wendy, 1, eggs
wendy, 3, chocolate, null, null, null
```

so it looks like wendy changed her list on weeks 1 and 3, but I'm only interested in 3

I did some searching (and maybe I'm not using the right key words).  I had a bit of a play with not exists - but that wasn't working either.
The full dataset may include subsequent weeks were wendy continues to buy chocolate.  I'm not interested in those - I'm only interested in the record where it changes.

Assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whether *Wendy* or *wendy*, I think there's a typo in `quent weeks were wendy conti`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want aggregation?  For each `name`, this returns the first week the name purchased chocolate:

```
select name, min(week)
from t
where item = 'chocolate'
group by name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  In my real dataset, it isn't necessarily chocolate.  I'm looking for any instance where the person changes the list (other than creating the first list), so over the course of a few weeks, a person might have two entries i am interested in (maybe Wendy gets sick from all the chocolate and goes back to bread and soup)

Comment: @batryingtocode . . . I interpret your question as clearly being "when was the first week when Wendy purchased chocolate".  If you have a different question, you might want to ask a *new* question with a clear explanation.

Comment: Ah I see, I said change at the bottom, but it did specifically say chocolate at the top.  I've edited it to make it clearer.